# How can i get all index on elastic search using elastic.js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, elasticsearch

With my angular application i need to display all indexes on elastic search. I am able to query a particular index using the documentation, not able to get all the indexes on the elastic search.

Here is the [`Documentation`](http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/)

Here is my code:

```
$scope.getallIndex = function(){
         $scope.Indexes =  ejs.Request().query(ejs.MatchAllQuery()
            .doSearch().then(function (body) {
         $scope.Indexes = body.hits.hits;
          console.log($scope.Indexes);       
        }
```

Comment: Hope this will help , http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_list_all_indexes.html#_list_all_indexes

Comment: @32teeths do you know how to  make this query using http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using elasticsearch.js which is the Browser build for Elastic Search that can be used in the browser . Refer [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/browser-builds.html) . I have maintained a factory :

```
 .factory('ElasticService', [ 'esFactory', function (elasticsearch) {
    var client = elasticsearch({
      host: ip + ':' + port,
    });  

client.cat.indices("b",function(r,q){
  console.log(r,q);
}) }]);
```

That will return all the indices .Refer [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-cat-indices) for full configuration.

Edited : 
Below is the full factory for retrieving data from a specific index .

```
 .factory('ElasticService', ['$q', 'esFactory', '$location', function ($q, elasticsearch, $location) {
var client = elasticsearch({
  host: ip + ':' + port
});


var search = function (index, body) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  client.search({
    index: index,
    type: type,
    body: body
  }).then(function (result) {
    var took = result.took;
    var size = result.hits.total;
    var ii = 0, hits_in, hits_out = [],aggs = [], highlight = [];
    hits_in = (result.hits || {}).hits || [];
    /* For the timebeing i have maintained this variable to save the aggregations */
    aggs = result.aggregations;
    for (; ii < hits_in.length; ii++) {
      hits_in[ii].fields.id = hits_in[ii]._id;
      hits_out.push(hits_in[ii].fields);
      // hits_out[hits_in[ii]._id]=hits_in[ii].fields: use this method if you wanna keep _id as the index

      // if there is a highlight coming along with the data we add a field highlight and push it to built an array
      if (hits_in[ii].highlight) {
        highlight.push(hits_in[ii].highlight);
      }
    }
    if (highlight.length) {
      deferred.resolve({hits: hits_out, highlight: highlight,aggs:aggs, size: size, took: took});
    }
    else {
      deferred.resolve({hits: hits_out, size: size,aggs:aggs, took: took});
    }

  }, deferred.reject);
  return deferred.promise;
};
return {search: search};  }]);
```

And so the controller you can use this factory for fetching data from a particular index

```
  ElasticService.search('<index>', <query>).then(function (resp) {
    // resp has the content
  });
```

Comment: Thanks , is it possible to perform the data retrieval and insert using this in angualr?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I have edited it with function for retrieving data .

Answer (score 10):

```
  const indices = await client.cat.indices({format: 'json'})
```

Answer (score 3):

I did query like below in javascript and it returned me index list

```
client.cat.indices({
  h: ['index']
}).then(function (body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The elasticsearch JS API has a method to query all the indices on the instance: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-cat-indices

Only thing is that it doesn't really return to you in a readable JSON format. So what I end up doing is something like the following

```
client.cat.indices({
  h: ['index', 'docs.count']
}).then(function (body) {
  let lines = body.split('\n');
  let indices = lines.map(function (line) {
    let row = line.split(' ');
    return {name: row[0], count: row[1]};
  });
  indices.pop(); //the last line is empty by default
});
```